# Bash: how can I run `sudo -n true` in the background without interfering with `read`?

Tags: bash, sudo, read

I have a long running Bash script that I don't want to run as root, but it needs root access periodically throughout. I solved this by asking for the user for the root password using

```
sudo -v
```

and then I backgrounded a process that would loop and reset the sudo timer using

```
sudo -n true
```

I then started to have weird problems when using `read` in the main process. Here is a minimal script exhibiting this problem. If you run it and don't input anything before the `sudo -n true` is run, the read gets a `read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo -v  # ask user for password

sleep 1 && sudo -n true &  # background a process to reset sudo

printf "Reading text: "
read -n 1 TEXT
echo "Read text: $TEXT"
```

I haven't been able to replicate this behavior with any other command besides `sudo`. How can I run `sudo -n true` in the background without interfering with `read`?

*Edit:*

I only get this problem on Ubuntu not macOS.

Comment: Does it work any better if you use `sudo -v` again instead of `sudo -n true`?

Comment: No it gives the identical behavior.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get the same behaviour with:

```
sleep 1 && true < /dev/tty &
read var
```

`sudo` opens `/dev/tty` to query the current foreground process group, that causes the `read()` system call made by bash's `read` to return with EAGAIN with Ubuntu 18.04's Linux  kernel 4.15.0-45-generic and 4.18.0-14-generic at least causing the `read` utility to return with that error.

That seems to be caused by [a bug in recent versions of the Ubuntu variants of the Linux kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873). I can't reproduce it on Solaris nor FreeBSD, nor in any version of Linux on Debian (though I can reproduce it if I boot Debian on Ubuntu's 4.18 kernel).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1815021 seems to be another manifestation of that bug.

That's introduced by https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/11/1/663 which ubuntu backported to both its 4.15 and 4.18 kernels at least. But Ubuntu had not backported [another change](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d3736d82e8169768218ee0ef68718875918091a0) that fixes [a regression introduced by that patch](https://marc.info/?l=linux-console&m=154883021430618&w=2) until [2 hours ago](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873/comments/4).

4.18.0-15-generic has now landed in the Ubuntu repositories and fixes the issue. I suppose the one for 4.15 will follow shortly.

`ksh93` doesn't have the problem for that same code as its `read` builtin uses `select()` first to wait for input, and `select()` doesn't return when the other process opens `/dev/tty`.

So here you could use `ksh93` instead of `bash` or wait for the fixed kernel or go back to 4.15.0-43 until 4.15.0-46 is released.

Alternatively, you could use `zsh` which has builtin support for changing uids (via the EUID/UID/USERNAME special variables) provided you start the script as `root` so you wouldn't need to run `sudo` within the script (it's also potentially dangerous to extend the life of the sudo token longer than the user would expect).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that testcase (what bash version is that?) -- but I don't see how another process opening `/dev/tty` could cause a `read` to return with `EAGAIN`; surely isn't it because of a SIGCHLD with CLD_STOPPED (itself caused by a SIGTTIN)? Is there some known bug explaining that?

Comment: @mosvy, no, as confirmed by `strace`, it's definitely the `open()` on `/dev/tty` that triggers the `read()` to return with EAGAIN. On that system, I can reproduce with any shell or utility that does a `read()` on the terminal device.

Comment: Hmm, the only way I could make a blocking read return `EAGAIN` is by setting O_NONBLOCK on the same file object -- but opening `/dev/tty` will not return the same file object as eg. `/dev/pts/4`. eg `sleep 1 && perl -MFcntl=F_SETFL,F_GETFL,O_NONBLOCK -e 'fcntl STDIN, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK' & read foo` will not cause the read to fail with EAGAIN if perl's input is redirected from `/dev/tty` instead.

Comment: or with `ioctl(FIONBIO, [1])` which is the same thing as `fcntl(O_NONBLOCK)`. That testcase is really puzzling, so sorry for the stupid question: would a `cat` in the terminal block (expect input) before or after that?

Comment: @mosvy, note that I get that error with `bash -c 'sleep 1 && true < /dev/tty & read var'` with 4.18 on Ubuntu but not on Debian, it may also be down to sysctl options. I'm going to try and narrow down what causes it on Ubuntu. In any case while EAGAIN is meant to be returned from non-blocking open file descriptions, it's not the case here, it looks like a specific behaviour of the pty driver with those kernels.

Comment: @mosvy, I can reproduce the problem if I boot Debian on the Ubuntu kernel. It looks like a kernel bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1815021 seems related. Ubuntu has backported https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/11/1/663

Comment: thanks for going at the bottom of it & sorry for my disbelief -- that was quite a tough one, though.