# Why does scp's strict filename checking reject quoted last component but not others?

Tags: quoting, filenames, scp

When I try to scp a file with a slash in its path, the path is quoted for the local host, and the last path component is additionally quoted for the remote host, like `scp host:"a/b/'c'" .`, it fails with

```
protocol error: filename does not match request
```

unless I use the `-T` option. However, if *any other* path component is quoted, like `scp host:"a/'b'/c" .`, it works. Also, if the path is *not* quoted for the local host, like `scp host:a/b/'c' .`, it works.

The man page documents `-T` as:

> Disable strict filename checking.  By default when copying files from a remote host to a local directory scp checks that the received filenames match those requested on the command-line to prevent the remote end from sending unexpected or unwanted files.  Because of differences in how various operating systems and shells interpret filename wildcards, these checks may cause wanted files to be rejected.  This option disables these checks at the expense of fully trusting that the server will not send unexpected filenames.

I don't understand how this description explains the behavior I see. What is the rationale for scp's behavior? And is there any way to disable this "feature"?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and the remote host is running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Maybe the remote system removes the quotes and actually sends a file `a/b/c` which will be copied to `./c` on your local system. A file `c` does not match your pattern `"'c'"`. You disable the check with option `-T`. If you quote the directory `'b'` you will get a file named `c` irrespectively how the remote system interprets `a/'b'`. As the transferred file matches the specified pattern you don't need `-T`.

Comment: @Bodo That is a plausible explanation. Perhaps scp doesn't know what shell the remote host uses so it isn't sure that it can canonicalize `'c'` to `c`. But it is terribly inconvenient.

Comment: What do you expect to be copied by `scp host:"a/b/'c'" .`? A file `c`? A file `'c'` with single quotes in its name?

Comment: @Bodo I expect `a/b/'c'` to pass to the remote shell and the remote shell to interpret it as file `c` in folder `a/b`. In other words, the file names stored in the filesystems on the remote and local hosts would both be `c`. So ideally there would be no error without `-T`. And the local `scp` knows that it specified `'c'` and got back `c`. But it might not know that the two are the same in the respective filesystems.

Comment: Why do you have the nested quotes? If you execute `cp "a/b/'c'" .` the `cp` command would try to copy a file `'c'` because the inner single quotes are quoted by the outer double quotes. Your expectation how `scp` should interpret your strange file name might be confusing for others (for the authors of `scp`).

Comment: @Bodo I am in the habit of quoting when using scp because my file names often contain spaces. That way I don't need to worry about the local shell splitting the file or otherwise interpreting the string. The inner quotes are for the remote shell. But in the examples in the question the outer quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: You're not telling what systems you're using (both the local and the remote, and what login shells on each), and your problem is not reproducible with standard unix systems. Please post a real example of your problem with details (I bet that your file is not named `a/b/c`)

Comment: @UncleBilly I'm connecting from Ubuntu 16.04 running Bash to Ubuntu 12.04 running Bash. I reproduced this issue using the exact commands in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu people are known for pushing through inconsiderate/partial patches (recent [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499433/325065)); in your case, it's about [this patch](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/391ffc4b9d31fa1f4ad566499fef9176ff8a07dc), which is less than 3 weeks old, including the time spent in snapshots:

```
check in scp client that filenames sent during remote->local directory
copies satisfy the wildcard specified by the user.

This checking provides some protection against a malicious server
sending unexpected filenames, but it comes at a risk of rejecting wanted
files due to differences between client and server wildcard expansion rules.

For this reason, this also adds a new -T flag to disable the check.

reported by Harry Sintonen
fix approach suggested by markus@;
has been in snaps for ~1wk courtesy deraadt@

OpenBSD-Commit-ID: 00f44b50d2be8e321973f3c6d014260f8f7a8eda
```

That is not ready for prime time (it's naively using `fnmatch(3)` on the basename of the file) and already had to fixed to allow for brace [expansions](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/3d896c157c722bc47adca51a58dca859225b5874).

Conclusion: it's a bug; it'll probably be fixed sooner or later; or if not, be prepared to always disable this new misfeature with `-T`.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new on this site and didn't know scp would behave differently on Ubuntu than on other distros.